# Spring Cloud Data Flow AWS S3 bucket

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using SCDF Stream S3 SOURCE starter app to read file from aws S3 bucket. What configuration to be set in the s3 SOURCE app to avoid accessing the same file.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you solve your case?

Comment: cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey
<user access key>
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey
<user secret key>
cloud.aws.region.static
us-<region>
cloud.aws.stack.auto
false
cloud.aws.credentials.instanceProfile
false
spring.cloud.config.enabled
false
remote-dir
/<S3directory>
preserve-timestamp
true
markers-json 
true
local-dir
/<local-directory> in your machine
mode
ref

Comment: I ended-up with above config